# Are implied requests for suggestions like "I don't know what else to do" considered rhetorical statements?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

If someone says something such as, "I don't know what else to do," it kind of implies a request for some suggestions. In the case the person doesn't actually want ideas for what to do, would this be considered a rhetorical statment?

Comment: A rhetorical statement isn't expecting an answer.

Comment: @Steve Perhaps this is about the converse of a rhetorical question: a non-question seeking a response.

Answer (score 1):

According to [**Study.com**](https://study.com/learn/lesson/rhetorical-question.html#:%7E:text=A%20rhetorical%20statement%20is%20used,more%20frequently%20than%20rhetorical%20statements.) (though the broader definition ' A rhetorical statement is typically an assertion that uses devices or methods often found in rhetoric to become more meaningful or persuasive' can be found)

> *A rhetorical statement is used in the same way as a rhetorical*
> *question: it is a statement that is not intended to elicit a direct*
> *response from the reader. Rhetorical questions are used more*
> *frequently than rhetorical statements.*

I'm not sure I'd include trivial examples like 'It's raining cats and dogs.' / 'Hello.'; I think there has to be more substance. Probably adages. But the concept largely smacks to me of unsolicited advice with no desire to be contradicted. Even 'What a beautiful day!' or 'I'm out of ideas' invite a response.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, since statements in general are not intended to elicit responses. Questions normally do elicit a response, so the ones that don't need to be distinguished.

Comment: The idea I'm getting is that a response is not wished for. _Whatever I say, goes._ An arrogation. End of 'discussion'.